# RequireJS with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

I'm having problem to implement angular with require. When the screen starts not imprime the message of controller. Below following my codes.

[Scripts/Main.js]

```
require.config({

paths: {
    'angular': 'angular.min'
},

shim: {
    'angular': {
        exports : 'angular'
    }
}
});

require([
'../App/Controller/mainController'
])

[App/Controller/MainController.js]

require(['../app/app'], function (app) {

app.controller('MainController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Hello world';
});
});

[App/App]

define(['angular'], function (angular) {

return angular.module('MyApp', []);
});
```

[HTML]

```
<div class="row" ng-app="MyApp">
  <div ng-controller="MainController">
    {{message}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you should only have one `require` change it to `define` in `MainController.js`

Comment: Not an answer, but a pointer from a project of mine from which you may (or may not) get some ideas: [angular-require-lazy](https://github.com/nikospara/angular-require-lazy/).